# Emacs23 cannot be transparent in Ubuntu(Gnome 3)

Tags: emacs, transparent

I search how to transparent my emacs window. But it doesn't work.
Something like this failed:

```lisp
 (global-set-key [(f8)] 'loop-alpha)

 (setq alpha-list '((100 100) (95 65) (85 55) (75 45) (65 35)))

(defun loop-alpha ()
(interactive)
(let ((h (car alpha-list)))               
((lambda (a ab)
   (set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'alpha (list a ab))
   (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist (cons 'alpha (list a ab)))
   ) (car h) (car (cdr h)))
(setq alpha-list (cdr (append alpha-list (list h))))
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working implementation of what I think you were trying to do:

```lisp
(global-set-key [(f8)] 'loop-alpha)

(defvar alpha-list '((100 100) (95 65) (85 55) (75 45) (65 35)))

(defun next-alpha ()
  (let ((current-alpha
         (or (frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'alpha)
             (first alpha-list)))
        (lst alpha-list))
    (or (second
         (catch 'alpha
           (while lst
             (when (equal (first lst) current-alpha)
               (throw 'alpha lst))
             (setf lst (cdr lst)))))
        (first alpha-list))))

(defun loop-alpha ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((new-alpha (next-alpha))
        (current-default (assoc 'alpha default-frame-alist)))
    (set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'alpha new-alpha)
    (if current-default
        (setcdr current-default new-alpha)
      (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist (cons 'alpha new-alpha)))))
```

Notice that any version you write that redefines `alpha-list` is going to behave very strangely with multiple frames. I would explain what was wrong with your code, but I honestly couldn't work out what it was supposed to do. Note that this would be somewhat easier to write if I allowed myself to `(require 'cl)` first, but I think this code should work - it does here at any rate!

Comment: thank you, then how to impletment this with cl ? Only speedbar can became transparent, main frame is still opaque. Conflict with color-theme ??

Comment: The code sets the current frame's opacity, which is what I thought your original attempt was supposed to do. Try making sure the current window (as in, X11 toplevel window) is the main frame before hitting F8.

Comment: Oh, and the cl thing is a library that provides functions that one finds in common lisp. They would make the implementation of next-alpha significantly simpler, and I (at least) sometimes find setcdr hard to understand, which could be avoided using the cl code.